# display data multilevel JSON with underscore

Tags: json, underscore.js

I have this JSON:

```
    "models": [
                 {
                     "model": [
                                  {
                                       "hotspotid": "0",
                                       "modelproducts": ["hbeu50282393_406_21","hbeu50286435_404_21","hbeu50286087_279_21"]
                                  },
                                  {
                                        "hotspotid": "2",
                                        "modelproducts": ["hbeu50282393_406_21","hbeu50286435_404_21","hbeu50286087_279_21"]
                                   }
                               ],
                    "model": [
                                  {
                                       "hotspotid": "0",
                                       "modelproducts": ["hbeu50286435_404_21","hbeu50286087_279_21"]
                                  },
                                  {
                                        "hotspotid": "1",
                                        "modelproducts": ["hbeu50286435_404_21","hbeu50286087_279_21"]
                                   }
                               ]
                 }
            ]
```

An I would like to display the hotspotids for each mode using underscore. At the moment I have this:

```
   <% _.each( listItem.models, function( model, index ){ %>
       <% _.each( model.model, function( hotspot, index ){ %>
         <p><%= hotspot.hotspotid %></p>
<% }) %>
<% }) %>
```

But this only shows the hotspot ids for the first model, what do I need to do to adapt the code to show the hotspotids of both models? I can modify both the JSON and underscore script if need be.

Comment: Something seems off with your JSON, it looks like you've got an object that has two "model" properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `recursive function` to loop for desired deep nested properties.

I am using `underscore mixin` to create a `recursive function`. This is just an example but you can modify to suit your purpose.

```
_.mixin({
    // pass your json here
    recursive: function(obj) {
        // your result array of hotspotid
        var result = [];
        function recurse(val, index, list) {
            // if key value is object call this function recursively
            if(_.isObject(val)){
                _.each(val, recurse);
            } 
            // if you found the key do the desired operation
            else if(index=="hotspotid"){
                 result.push(val);
            }
        }
        recurse(obj);
        return result;
    }
});
var data = {
    "models": [
        {
            "model1": [
                 {
                    "hotspotid": "0",
                    "modelproducts": [
                        "hbeu50286435_404_21",
                         "hbeu50286087_279_21"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "hotspotid": "1",
                    "modelproducts": [
                        "hbeu50286435_404_21",
                        "hbeu50286087_279_21"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "model2": [
                {
                    "hotspotid": "0",
                    "modelproducts": [
                        "hbeu50286435_404_21",
                         "hbeu50286087_279_21"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "hotspotid": "1",
                     "modelproducts": [
                        "hbeu50286435_404_21",
                        "hbeu50286087_279_21"
                    ]
                }
            ]
         }
    ]
 };

 console.log(_.recursive(data));
```